# cannot convert from method group to eventcallback blazor (Server App) - Sync Fusion Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, syncfusion

I am using sync fusion grid in blazor server app. Inside grid I am using dropdown list. I wanna trigger the even on dropdown change event. When I try to bind the event using following code its giving me error "cannot convert from method group to eventcallback". Please help.

**Below is the razor HTML code**

```
<GridColumn HeaderText="Action" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="95">
    <Template>
        <SfDropDownList TItem="ActionDDLVM" Value="@((context as ActionDDLVM).Id)" TValue="string" PopupHeight="100px" Placeholder="Action" DataSource="@LstAction">
            <DropDownListEvents TValue="string" TItem="ActionDDLVM" OnValueSelect="OnSelect" ValueChange="ValueChange"></DropDownListEvents>
            <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="Text" Value="Id"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
        </SfDropDownList>
    </Template>
</GridColumn>
```

**Below is the code in C# component partial class**

```
public void OnSelect(SelectEventArgs args)
{

}

public void ValueChange(Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.ChangeEventArgs<string> args)
{
    // you can get changed value in args.Value
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a type? _"Declaration `public EventCallback<ChangeEventArgs<TValue, TItem>> ValueChange { get; set; }`"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event arguments of `OnValueSelect` and `ValueChange` were defined wrongly. Please find the modified code example below.

```
<GridColumn HeaderText="Action" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="95">
  <Template>
    <SfDropDownList TItem="ActionDDLVM" Value="@((context as ActionDDLVM).Id)" TValue="string" PopupHeight="100px" Placeholder="Action" DataSource="@LstAction">
      <DropDownListEvents TValue="string" TItem="ActionDDLVM" OnValueSelect="OnSelect" ValueChange="ValueChange" />
      <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="Text" Value="Id" />
    </SfDropDownList>
  </Template>
</GridColumn>
    
public void OnSelect(SelectEventArgs<ActionDDLVM> Args)
{
}
public void ValueChange(ChangeEventArgs<string, ActionDDLVM> Args)
{
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @user12702211 your solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The `ValueChanged` property is declared as `EventCallback<TValue>`, where `TValue` is `string` in your example.  This means the method parameter it's expecting is actually `string`, and not `ChangeEventArgs<string>`.  Therefore, changing your `ValueChange` method to use a `string` instead ought to fix this:

```
public void ValueChange(string value)
{
}
```

In contrast, the `OnChange` property is declared that way:

```
public EventCallback<ChangeEventArgs> OnChange
```

So perhaps that is what led to the confusion.